# Python - Calling function from main() function returns zero

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm writing a program that simulates the hacking mini game found in Fallout 3. The user is supposed to choose a difficulty level, and based on that the program will return a list of strings, then the user has 4 tries to correctly guess which word has been randomly selected by the program.

The problem I'm facing is that when I call the various functions I've written to handle the different aspects of the game, no value is returned. If I call each function separately and pass it the required parameters I get the correct output, but for some reason it won't work when I call them from the main() function. Here is my code:

```
import operator
import random


def difficulty_level(difficulty_choice):
    num_choices = 0
    word_length = 0
    if difficulty_choice == 1:
        num_choices = 5
        word_length = 5
    elif difficulty_choice == 2:
        num_choices = 8
        word_length = 9
    elif difficulty_choice == 3:
        num_choices = 10
        word_length = 13
    elif difficulty_choice == 4:
        num_choices = 12
        word_length = 17
    elif difficulty_choice == 5:
        num_choices = 15
        word_length = 21
    return num_choices, word_length


def generate_word_list(num_choices, word_length):
    matching_words = []
    word_choice_list = []
    word_source = open("enable1.txt", 'r')
    for word in word_source:
        if len(word) == word_length + 1:
            matching_words.append(word.rstrip())
    for i in range(num_choices):
        word_choice_list.append(random.choice(matching_words))
    return word_choice_list


def user_guesses(word_choice_list):
    guesses = 4
    game_over = False

    for word in word_choice_list:
        print word.upper()

    selected_word = random.choice(word_choice_list)
    selected_word_length = len(selected_word)

    while not game_over:
        guess_word = (raw_input("Guess (%s left)? " % guesses)).lower()
        if guess_word == selected_word:
            game_over = True
            print("You win!")
        else:
            num_correct_letters = map(operator.eq, guess_word, selected_word).count(True)
            guesses -= 1
            print("%s/%s correct" % (num_correct_letters, selected_word_length))


def main():
    game_level = raw_input("Difficulty (1-5)? ")
    main_num_choices, main_word_length = difficulty_level(game_level)
    word_list = generate_word_list(main_num_choices, main_word_length)
    user_guesses(word_list)

main()
```

I have no idea why it's not working. I'm writing this in PyCharm and using 2.7.6 as the compiler. Thanks.

Comment: I think it's a bit unclear what you're asking. Could you explain what exactly is happening a bit more?

Comment: `raw_input` in main returns a string. You are passing this string to difficulty_level. So it is returning default values which are 0. You need to convert the `game_level` to `int`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's working fine for me. I think maybe your issue is that you're expecting `game_level` to be an `int`, but it's actually a `str`. That's making `difficulty_level` return the wrong thing (it always returns `(0, 0)`), and that throws off the whole program. You can fix that very easily:

```
game_level = int(raw_input("Difficulty (1-5)? "))
```

Also, You're not closing "enable1.txt" after you open it. I recommend opening it like this, so that it gets closed automatically:

```
with open("enable1.txt", 'r') as word_source:
    for word in word_source:
        if len(word) == word_length + 1:
            matching_words.append(word.rstrip())
```

Comment: Wow do I feel silly. Thanks a lot for the quick response!